# update url with jQuery on select

Tags: jquery

I cant get the url to update when an item is selected. Here is my code:

```
jQuery("#switcher-select li a").click(function() {
    jQuery("#preview").attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("href"));
    jQuery("#purchase a").attr("href", jQuery(this).attr("data-demo"));
    jQuery("#purchase a").html('<span class="label">Get it now</span>');
    jQuery("#switcher-button").click();
    jQuery("#switcher-info").html(jQuery(this).find("h2").text() + '<span id="switcher-button"><i class="button-up"></i></span>');
    jQuery("#switcher-select li a").attr("data-selected", false);

    var selected = jQuery(this).attr("data-selected", true);
    window.location.href = "?theme=" + selected + "";

    jQuery("#switcher-select li a").each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).attr("data-selected") != "true") {
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: "#000"
            }, 400);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

        <ul id="switcher-select">
                <?php foreach( $theme_array as $theme) : ?>
                    <li id="<?php echo $theme["id"] ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $theme["demo_url"] ?>" data-demo="<?php echo $theme["theme_url"] ?>" data-selected="<?php if (ucfirst($theme["id"]) == $selected_theme) : echo "true"; else: echo "false"; endif; ?>">
                            <div class="switcher-theme-info">
                                <h2><?php echo ucfirst($theme["name"]) ?></h2>
                                <p><?php echo $theme["info"] ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul id="first-theme" class="demo-preview">
                            <li><img style="border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;" src="<?php echo $theme["screenshot"] ?>"/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
```

all i want is `#switcher-select li` ID when the `data-selected` is true.

I get this:
     http://localhost:8888/demo/?item=[object%20Object]

Comment: Please also add your HTML. You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The setter of `attr()` returns a jQuery object. This is then coerced to a string as `[object Object]` when you append it to the URL. It's not clear what value you're expecting, but as you're setting it to `true` I would assume you can just append `true` in the URL manually...?

Comment: Also note that the `document.ready` handler function takes a single parameter which is jQuery itself, so you can still use the `$` alias within the function scope even though you may have called `$.noConflict()`. This avoids all the ugly `jQuery()` calls

Comment: @secelite updated question. 

@RoryMcCrossan all i want is `#switcher-select li` ID when the data-selected is true on the url

Comment: @HiroHito please provide the HTML output (after processed PHP).

Comment: @HiroHito, put your php code above, so that afer DOM is ready your jquery will execute